# Internationalization Support for backend Messages in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I am trying to implement internationalization in my application. I already went through many blogs & tutorials which explain how we can implement it using different libraries.

The one I am planning to use is I18N with spring.

My application's structure is something like this :-

My application's front end (***based on Angular2***) consumes Rest APIs that are exposed from the backend. 
I am using Spring Rest for implementing the Rest APIs. For every API call I am preparing & sending appropriate messages to UI.

Now by default messages are in English but now I want to add internationalization support to it. How can I do it ?

Below is the example of one of the Rest API that I am exposing and the way I'm sending the messages :-

```
@CrossOrigin(methods = RequestMethod.POST)
@PostMapping(value = "/user/resetUserAccount", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> resetUserAccount(@RequestBody InputObj inputObj) {

    boolean isUserAccountReset = userService.resetUserAccount(inputObj);

    if (isUserAccountReset) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(successResponse("User Account Reset Successful").toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(failureResponse("Failed to Reset User Account").toString(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

I have written 2 helper methods given below that prepare the response messages :-

```
private JSONObject successResponse(String apiMessage) {
    JSONObject success = new JSONObject();
    success.put("reponse", "success");
    success.put("message", apiMessage);
    return success;
}

private JSONObject failureResponse(String apiMessage) {
    JSONObject failure= new JSONObject();
    success.put("reponse", "failure");
    success.put("message", apiMessage);
    return failure;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to the configuration class

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
 SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
 slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US); // Set default Locale as US
 return slr;
}

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
 ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
 source.setBasenames("i18n/messages");  // name of the resource bundle 
 source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
 return source;
}
```

Create a new directory named i18n inside resources directory and put your messages.properties and the other internationalized property files like  messages_ru.properties, messages_fr.properties etc inside it. Create message key and values like below:

**messages.properties**

```
msg.success=User Account Reset Successful
msg.failure=Failed to Reset User Account
```

Now inject the MessageSource Bean where you want to internationalize the message, i.e. your controller and then accept the Locale from headers in controller method and get messages from properties files like below:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@CrossOrigin(methods = RequestMethod.POST)
@PostMapping(value = "/user/resetUserAccount", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> resetUserAccount(@RequestHeader("Accept-Language") Locale locale, @RequestBody InputObj inputObj) {

    boolean isUserAccountReset = userService.resetUserAccount(inputObj);

    if (isUserAccountReset) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(successResponse(messageSource.getMessage("msg.success",null,locale)).toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(failureResponse(messageSource.getMessage("msg.failure",null,locale)).toString(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Comment: Why the `LocaleResolver` if `messageSource.getMessage()` requires a parameter locale, which is "manually" retrieved from the request-header? How can the `LocaleResolver` be used?